# Failed to start Open vSwitch Forwarding Unit

Tags: 18.04, update-alternatives

Tried to install `openvswitch-switch-dpdk` on ubuntu 18.04 (in vmware) following this instructions: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/openvswitch-dpdk

But after running this command:

`sudo update-alternatives --set ovs-vswitchd /usr/lib/openvswitch-switch-dpdk/ovs-vswitchd-dpdk`

The `sudo service openvswitch-switch restart`  fails with this output in the `journal -xe`:

```
-- Automatic restarting of the unit ovs-vswitchd.service has been scheduled, as 
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Apr 11 04:15:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Open vSwitch Forwarding Unit.
-- Subject: Unit ovs-vswitchd.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ovs-vswitchd.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 11 04:15:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: ovs-vswitchd.service: Start request repeated 
Apr 11 04:15:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: ovs-vswitchd.service: Failed with result 'exi
Apr 11 04:15:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Open vSwitch Forwarding Unit.
-- Subject: Unit ovs-vswitchd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ovs-vswitchd.service has failed.
```

I appreciate any help to get this working.

Comment: Is there anything more useful at the default log file in /var/log/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.log  ?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem I had to install `openvswitch-switch-dpdk`.

```
sudo apt-get install openvswitch-switch-dpdk
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for EAL to work, you must first bind a NIC to it using `dpdk-devbind` command before restarting the daemon, otherwise, the daemon fails. However, this breaks your internet connection and not necessary if you don't have traffic from outside. But this was the only way I could fix the error.